# HIVE UDF keep value from previous row

Tags: java, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a UDF that should return the content of the previous row. I implemented it with the following code. Unfortunately it always returns the value of the current row of parameter second. Does anyone have an idea what I am doing wrong?

```
@UDFType(stateful = true)   

public class Strip extends UDF {    

private Text result = new Text();
private static ArrayList<Text> lst;
int count=0;

public Strip(){
    result.set("");
}
public Text evaluate(Text first, Text second) {

    if (str == null | stripChars == null) {
return null;
}
if (lst == null)
{
    lst = new ArrayList<Text>();
    lst.add(second);        
    return first;
}

result=lst.get(lst.size()-1);
lst.add(second);    
return result;

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you pl show how you are passing values to this UDF

Comment: SELECT tmptime, Strip(min,max) From Bounds

Comment: instead of @UDFType(stateful = true) try using @UDFType(deterministic = false, stateful = true)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but the problem is still there. Always on the lst.add command all elements are changed to the value of second. But the size of list is increased on every call. Do you have any clue whats the matter with that?

Comment: it is weird as you are retrieving the result before adding the item.

Comment: Thats the purpose of the Program, I want to output the value of the previous row.

Comment: Yes thats what m saying as you are retrieving result before adding the item it should work. So it should not take "second" parameter value. Is it possible that every time same value is getting passed and so you are not able to identify whether its working or not. As size is increasing means values are there in arraylist.

Comment: I tested your suggestion with putting the lst.add command in front of the assignement of result. But it did not change the output. @Rajen Did you test the code? Did it work at your side?